# Histogram distribution

Tags: histograms

Imagine the following data:

```
data = {-0.7, -0.5, -0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.1}
```

From that I make a `Histogram`:

```
Histogram[data, {1}]
```

The output plot is:

[image]

I would like another way of binning the data:

The bins should be symmetric around the integer numbers:

```
]-1.5,-0.5]: 2 counts
]-0.5,+0.5]: 4 counts
]+0.5,+1.5]: 5 counts
]+1.5,+2.5]: 1 count
```

**Added**: It should work also for other bin width's:

e.g. `for bin width = 2` the intervals are `...]-3,-1], ]-1,+1], ]+1,+3], etc ...`

How can that be done? The number and tick marks should be centered below the bins.

I saw in many examples that the normal binning is used and that only the tick marks and position of the numbers at the x axis were shifted, which is here not the same.

Comment: I deleted my comment as it did the labeling correct, but didn't bin according to your specs...

Comment: What is the general criterion for the bin *center*? For your **Added** example, how do you choose whether to center the bins at even integers rather than odd integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick n dirty:

```
Histogram[data - 10^-10, {-1.5, 2.5, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... for bin size=0.5 I would use `Histogram[data - 10^-10, {-1.25, 2.25, 0.5}]`, which is correct, and for bin size=2 `Histogram[data - 10^-10, {-3, 3, 2}]`. Can that procedure be expressed as function of bin size?

Comment: seems like it would be hard to generalize. Maybe look at `FindDivisions`

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this? It's not well-tested, so I can't guarantee that the bin labels will always line up with the correct bin, but that can be tweaked pretty easily.

```
data = {-0.7, -0.5, -0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.1};
BarChart[
  Reverse@BinCounts[-data, {-#2 + 0.5, -#1 + 0.5, 1}], 
  ChartLabels -> Range @@ {#1, #2}
 ] & @@ {Floor@Min@data, Ceiling@Max@data}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... but exactly ... see above, the bin around -1 (>-1.5 and <=-0.5) has 2 counts etc.

Comment: I see: both `Histogram` and `BinCounts` have the closed end of the interval on the left, and you want it on the right. I think I can figure that out...

Comment: @mrz. Does that work? Again, I'm not sure if it's general, and it seems like there should be some option for `Histogram` that makes it work, but I can't find it yet.

Comment: see **Added** ... but it works ... can you make it general? I put into your code `BarSpacing -> None`

Comment: @mrz. I'll work on it, but unfortunately I'm out of time for now!